# Java - Android Development - Collision Problems

Tags: java, android

I'm making a side-scrolling shooter game using solely the eclipse IDE for mobile development, but seems to be having a bit of a problem when it comes to the bullet colliding with the enemy objects, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Anyone know why this is happening?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
               `boolean aabulletHit = Rect.intersects(abulletDst, aenemyDst);
                if (aabulletHit) {
                    aenemyx1 = -100;aenemyx2 = -30;
                    abulletx1 = 1000; abulletx2 = 1115; 
                }
                boolean abbulletHit = Rect.intersects(abulletDst, benemyDst);
                if (abbulletHit) {
                    benemyx1 = -100;benemyx2 = -30;
                    abulletx1 = 1000; abulletx2 = 1115; 
                }
                boolean acbulletHit = Rect.intersects(abulletDst, cenemyDst);
                if (acbulletHit) {
                    cenemyx1 = -100;cenemyx2 = -30;
                    abulletx1 = 1000; abulletx2 = 1115; 
                }
                boolean adbulletHit = Rect.intersects(abulletDst, denemyDst);
                if (adbulletHit) {
                    denemyx1 = -100;denemyx2 = -30;
                    abulletx1 = 1000; abulletx2 = 1115; 
                }
                boolean aebulletHit = Rect.intersects(abulletDst, eenemyDst);
                if (aebulletHit) {
                    eenemyx1 = -100;eenemyx2 = -30;
                    abulletx1 = 1000; abulletx2 = 1115; 
                }`
```

Another problem I'm having is that the scrolling BG doesn't seem to be showing up as well.

Comment: How big are the enemy rectangles? How big are the bullet rectangles? How much do they move each frame? If they move too fast, the problem might be that the bullet moves from one side of the enemy at one frame to the other side of the enemy at the next frame without ever colliding with the enemy. Does that seem plausible?

Comment: the enemies are pretty big compared to the bullets. 
bullets are 15x15 pixels while the enemies are 70 x 40 pixels. both move at 10 pixels per iteration

Comment: not at all, in the device im testing on, you could literally see the objects overlapping each other

Comment: ok - probably not it then :) (sorry accidentally deleted my previous comment)

Comment: Android's Rect constructor parameters are (left, top, right, bottom) rather than (left, top, width, height) as one would expect - are you making sure you give parameters in that way? (right = left+width, bottom = top+height)?

Comment: yup i, set each of the parameters as x1,y1,x2,y2 for both bullet and enemy, for example: enemy1x1,enemy1x2, and so on.

Comment: Ok. Last suggestion :) Perhaps it is a coordinate system issue (where the objects (and also rectangles) are in different coordinate systems). Have you tried drawing the rectangles (in the same coordinate system - i.e. without doing any transformations between them) or checked their values?

Comment: if you mean my onDraw method, then yes im using the same on draw method for both

Comment: and you're not doing any (for example) Canvas.translate()/rotate()/scale() calls between drawing them? (those change the coordinate system matrix)

Comment: hmmm , oh i have this one line of code that scales the whole canvas: canvas.scale(X,Y);

Comment: so if you draw the rectangles in one simple loop (without the scale call inbetween), do the rectangles still overlap when the bullets/enemies overlap? (for example: for (Rect rect : rectangles) canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);)

Comment: they still do :/ i tried commenting out the scale code and they still seem to be just passing one another